# Server Side rendering static html with NodeJS and routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-ui-router, server-side-rendering

I have an Angular 4 app that has a lot of static content that the user can interact with.
The issue I am facing is to server side render the app so that google can reference its content.
As you may know, making an Angular 4 app render from the server is a real pain as soon as you use UI libraries such as Angular Material or PrimeNG...

The idea that I am trying to implement is to generate all the pages in the client, save the html in a separate html files, and make NodeJS render those files in a static way so that google can see it when it parses the web site, but also to speed up the rendering for users.

All my urls follow this pattern :
https://www.mywebsite.com/XXXX/page_id/yyyy

The question is how do I extract page_id from the url, and render a static html file (page_id.html) previously created to that same url ?

Comment: try `url.split('/')[4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am serving static html, here is the solution I came up with :

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");


var app = express();

app.get('*.*', express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

app.get('/xxx/:pageId/yyy', function(req, res) {        
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/'+req.params.pageId + '.html'));
});
```